# Extract paths to nested fields for properties that are optional in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a use case where I need to extract all possible paths to nested fields inside a TypeScript `interface`.

When I define a property within the "main" type that has nested and optional properties, then it works as expected. However, I am running into an issue with an optional property that points to another interface.

```
type NestedKeyOf<T extends object> = {
  [Key in keyof T & (string | number)]: T[Key] extends object
    ? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<T[Key]>}`
    : `${Key}`;
}[keyof T & (string | number)];

interface MyParameters {
  Foo: string;
  Bar?: string;
}

interface MyObject {
  Parameters?: MyParameters;
  Foo: {
    Bar?: string;
  }
}

// Here, I'd expect "Parameters.Foo" and "Parameters.Bar" to also exist
// Instead, all I get is "Parameters" | "Foo" | "Foo.Bar"

type Path = NestedKeyOf<MyObject> // "Parameters" | "Foo" | "Foo.Bar"
```

- [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMDSEQHkBmAeAKlBAB5IB2y8UA9gEYBWEAxsAHxQC8UA3gFBRQA2uhBQAlmSgBrDNWxRCAMigAKRACcJAcygAfKGQCuAW1oR1ASgC6ALgXCMVoqQgUqdRi34CoAfigABgAk3CIAvgF6gSHhAHQhcIgoIjgEDiBWrBHeAnbBoRgRANy8YYIyIHIKUMpqwJpkOvpGpubWJbwSSOrYAIZM0ACyIAAKveq9xhDdVHwCAGLU1HYa2iUCAELjviv1a6W8nWTdfQNQw5gMzMA83mMTUzM756Pjk9Pm8OtQi8u3PlAtupnqtGt8wgdeAB6KFQAAS5ggABooABJADkyGckBYUAARPd3jNYr88VBJliCW9Hp9YkCycBqOSADbwJkkMSIaGwiRJXrIFGomhkZmiLTTfGEmnqeBk-R40lRBVLOnjPG8UCQKBjYAAC04sAQSDQGFSFyuLFYvCAA)

Could someone please explain what is the reason for this behavior?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `type Test = MyObject["Parameters"] extends object ? true : false` evaluates to `false` if Parameters is optional. You can fix it by excluding the case of it being undefined with `Exclude<T[Key], undefined> extends object` instead of `T[Key] extends object` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMDSEQHkBmAeAKlBAB5IB2y8UA9gEYBWEAxsAHxQC8UA3gFBRQA2uhBQAlmSgBrDNWxRCAMigAKRACcJAcygAfKGQCuAW1oR1ASgC6ALigBRYkwA2h5BALCMVgDRRDFBDYEijsJOSUNAzMwPwCUAD8UAAGACTcIgC+yXop6VkAdOlwiCgiOLiOLm4e+F4gvv6BwWShrNlxAnZpGRjZANy8mYIyIHIKUMpqwJpkOvpGpubWg7wSSOrYAIZM0ACyIAAKW+pbxhAbVHwCAGLU1HYa2oMCAEInCY8zz0O8a2Qbba7KAHTDRFg8OLHU7nS6fEFHE5nC7meAvKB3B6Q+JQd7qeFPObozK-XgAejJUAAEuYIH4AJIAcmQRGIkAhACJocjLgVMRyoGcWVykbDUQU8QLgNRBc54DKSGJEOTKRJSltkAyaGRnKItBcoCKYSj1PABfoOfzcpb7hKThzeKBIFBjsAABacWAIJBoDAVUHgthAA)):

```js
type NestedKeyOf<T extends object> = {
  [Key in keyof T & (string | number)]: Exclude<T[Key], undefined> extends object
    ? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<Exclude<T[Key], undefined>>}`
    : `${Key}`;
}[keyof T & (string | number)];

interface MyParameters {
  Foo: string;
  Bar?: string;
}

interface MyObject {
  Parameters?: MyParameters;
  Foo: {
    Bar?: string;
  }
}

type Path = NestedKeyOf<MyObject>
```